# К какому роду сводить слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

«Резкий безжалостный Алексеев «Подъем!» разбудил Мишаню рано утром» или «Резкое безжалостное Алексеево «Подъем!» разбудило Мишаню рано утром». Вопрос. Сводить к  мужскому роду, т.к. «Подъем» муж. рода или к среднему, т.к . подразумеваем существительное «слово»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мужской род можно грамматически отнести только к Алексееву (если **он** разбудил своим приказом). Если же разбудило **то**, что он произнёс, то без прямого видового наименования формы речи род - средний (***нечто*** им произнесённое), независимо от цитируемого содержания, поскольку затруднительно домыслить, что именно это было (приказ, указание или побудка).

> Резкий и безжалостный Алексеев своим «Подъем!» разбудил Мишаню рано
>   утром.
>
> Резкое и безжалостное Алексеевское «Подъем!» разбудило Мишаню рано
>   утром.

Comment: Благодарю. Поняла объяснение. Буду применять в подобных случаях.

Answer (score 2):

***Резкое, безжалостное Алексеево «Подъем!» разбудило Мишаню рано утром.***

Этот вариант звучит лучше. Средний род прилагательных помогает правильно понять фразу, тогда как употребление мужского рода вносит недопонимание, ср.: *Резкий, безжалостный Алексеев подъём разбудил Мишаню.*

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение и предложенный вариант предложения. Все поняла.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать так:

**Резкое, безжалостное (требование)  «Подъем!» разбудило Мишаню рано утром.**

Притяжательная форма ***Алексеев*** совершенно не смотрится в данной конструкции и  воспринимается **как стилистическая погрешность.** То, что разбудил Мишаню именно Алексей, должно быть ясно из контекста.

Comment: Мне кажется, что @Белка имеет в виду не фамилию Алексеев, а имя Алексей.

Comment: Точно, я тоже имела в виду Алексея.

Comment: Благодарю, Sharon, за предложенный вариант! Честно. Это очень правильно предлагать человеку поиграть со словами, выбросить лишнее. Но «Алексеево», думаю, и весьма упрямо думаю, требуется. Ниже, следующим комментарием, предоставила предложение полностью. Можно написать: «Казалось бы, должен был Алексей смягчиться…», тем обойтись без «Адексеево» — не хочу. Потому что в связке с другими предложениями играет именно ниже приведенный вариант. Прошу, если что со знаками препинания не так: укажите. У меня обычно много «не так» — любое правило или переиначиваю, или напрочь забываю, потом краснею.

Comment: Казалось бы, должен был смягчиться, прикрепиться к брату состраданием, но нет — резкое, безжалостное Алексеево «Подъем!» разбудило Мишаню рано утром, а за обеденным столом подлетело к нему злое: «Зачем с Рыбтом медлишь?».

Comment: Да, Вы правы,  здесь без притяжательного прилагательного не обойтись, поэтому  всегда очень  важен контекст. Слово, которое не казалось подходящим к одной конструкции, в полном варианте выглядит как интересное авторское решение.